# Visualize AWS S3 data

Tags: amazon-s3, visualization

I have JSON data in AWS S3 bucket which I want to visualize on a public website with a custom domain name.

I'm looking for suggestions how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but your question does not contain enough information to be able to assist you. Could you possibly Edit your question to add more details? For example, what do you mean by "visualize on a public website"? What have you tried so far? Can you show us your code? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes, I agree my question is vague, sorry about that.  I wrote (and learned) a lot of Python, Twilio, ReactJS and AWS to get my data into S3 but am struggling with getting data out of S3 and haven't started implementing anything yet.  What I mean by 'visualize on a public website' is to make this data available publicly, shown on a line chart, pie chart, or similar.

Comment: You should at least more details on what kind of data you want to visualize - is that some kind of timeseries? dataset? metrics? There might be a lot of difference ways and the best suited will definitely depend on your data and what you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Athena + QuickSight might be a good combination. Here is a basic tutorial:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyze-and-visualize-nested-json-data-with-amazon-athena-and-amazon-quicksight/

Comment: Thank you Anton.  I looked at Athena + QS but it did not meet my needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing specific that AWS provides to 'visualize data on a public website'.

However, data is typically stored in a database and [AWS offers many different databases](https://aws.amazon.com/products/databases/). It's then a matter of finding a web-based visualization library that you can incorporate into your website, such as [vis.js](https://visjs.org/) or [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart).

You'll also need some type of "compute" layer, either in your back-end, or with AWS Lambda or perhaps just in JavaScript. This layer controls what the users are allowed to access and transforms requests into database queries.